# Getting 401 error in WordPress while using valid JWT token to insert HTML on page

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, jwt

I generate a token with JWT , and then I try to send an html code in a page wordpress.
The error I get is a 401 error, what did I do wrong?
(I put my JWT define in wp-content)
And I do receive a valid token.

I first do this code, it gives me a valid token :

```
$url = 'http://localhost/wordpress/index.php?rest_route=/jwt-auth/v1/token';
$data = array(
    'username' => 'admin',
    'password' => 'root'
);

$response = wp_remote_post($url, array
(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'headers' => array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ),
    'body' => wp_json_encode($data)
));

if (is_wp_error($response))
{
    $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
    echo "Error request : " . $error_message;
} else {
    $response_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response);
    $response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);

    if ($response_code === 200) {
        $response_data = json_decode($response_body, true);
        $token = $response_data['token'];
        echo "Token : ";
        var_dump($response_data);
    } else {
        echo "Error Code : " . $response_code;
    }
}
```

I have error code 401 here :

```
$page_id = 120; // ID page

$new_content = '<p>insert html page</p>';

$data = array
(
    'content' => array(
        'rendered' => $new_content)
);

$api_url = 'http://localhost/wordpress/index.php?rest_route=/wp/v2/pages/';
$url = $api_url . $page_id;
$response = wp_remote_post($url, array(
    'method' => 'POST', 
    'headers' => array(
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token
    ),
    '<body>' => wp_json_encode($data)
));

if (is_wp_error($response))
{
    $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
    echo "Error : $error_message";
}
else
{
    $response_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response);
    if ($response_code === 200 || $response_code === 201)
    {
        echo "Succes !";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error Code : $response_code";
    }
}
```

I tried to modify the user_status in my SQL database, thinking that it was an access problem.
I also used a code that checks if my token is valid.
I add too :
`define('JWT_AUTH_EXPIRATION', 3600);`

I also put as .htaccess :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

So after several tests and debugs, I think my Apache server, can't access .htacess, for example $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] , returns nothing to me.

If that's the problem, how do I configure Apache to read my .htaccess?
(I tried to put AllowOverride All / restart apache) nothing helps.

---

I finally found the answer!
I put the link:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/407971/getting-401-access-denied-when-trying-to-use-the-rest-api

Wordpress requires special activation, if your site is not https

You can put define`'WP_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE', 'development');` in wp-config.php

My new code:

```
    $this->username = 'admin';
    $this->application_password = 'xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx';

    $url = 'http://localhost/wordpress/index.php?rest_route=/wp/v2/pages';
    $json = json_encode
    ([
        'title' => 'Post using REST API',
        'content' => 'Post content using REST API',
        'status' => 'publish',
    ]);

    $data = [
        'http' => [
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => [
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($this->username . ':' . $this->application_password),
            ],
            'content' => $json,
        ],
    ];


    $context = stream_context_create($data);
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    if ($response === false)
    {
        $error = error_get_last();
        if($error !== null)
        {
            echo 'Error Request : ' . $error['message'];
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Error Request unknow.';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Response : ' . $response;
    }
```